# DoDirectPayment Method in Paypal advanced

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on paypal api. As client said he has purchased the paypal business account where his customer's can pay money on his own website and then I came through the DoDirectPayment method and worked on it and it was working on the sandbox but it was not working on live account. 
It shows error  as 
   "Invalid Configuration : This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant      configuration." 
and after bit search I came to know that account should be payment pro. Client gave me a link that he has purchased the paypal advanced and the link is ["https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced"](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced)

And when I saw the account type it shows the only business account. Where can we can check the exact account type?? Is there any option where I can check the merchant type. I am bit confused. I think client needs to pay extra for payment pro as written on website. Can I use DoDirectPayment method in paypal advanced. On paypal it shows three type of account type personal  personal, premier and business account. After subscription for business account does he need to subscribe for others like advance pro and standard? and what all other methods we can use for paypal advance. 
I am new so I am bit confused and I didn't found any suitable document..
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal Payments Advanced product does not support DoDirectPayment API. Advanced makes use of pages (layouts) hosted by PayPal and credit card data is posted to the server using a secure token. See [PayPal Payments Advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced/) for a detailed explanation of how it works and links to all of the documentation.

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer. as Client is saying that he has subscribed for paypal advanced, how do I check that on paypal dashboard. I am unable to check. and do I need to subscribe for payflow service? While creating test account it is asking to update to pro account. and client do not want to update it pro account. Is it necessary to update it to live?? :)

Comment: [Testing with the Payflow gateway](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/) is a step by step guide. To avoid lengthy comment strings, additional questions should be directed to [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/ask).